# How to install pyspark plugin in PyCharm

Tags: ubuntu, python, pycharm

When I try to install `pyspark plugin` in `PyCharm`, I get an error
`Make sure that you use the correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter located at '/usr/bin/python2.7'`
However, when I type `pip --version` in the terminal, I see this version:

`pip 8.1.2 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)`

So, cannot figure out what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyCharm can have more than one interpreter.  When you run pip from the command line, the system is finding the first pip it can find based on your PATH settings, not necessarily the one you're using within PyCharm.

In Preferences -> Project at the top will be a dropdown of the python interpreters. Click the drop down, and show all.  Then in a terminal window, ensure there's a pip for each one.

[image]

You would do this by running the ensurepip module using each python. So in my example highlighted I would run

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3 -m ensurepip
```

to ensure I have pip for that version of python.  Do similar for the other pythons of interest.